# Pandas Dataframe sort_values() multiple column with custom key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I'm trying to sort by `level` first, followed by `reviews`. The dataframe `dtype` are all `str`.

```
ranking_level_sort = {
    "Exceptional": 5,
    "Excellent": 4,
    "Very good": 3,
    "Good": 2,
    "Review score": 1,
    "None": 0
}

hotel_sorted = hotel.sort_values(by=["level", "reviews"],  key=lambda x: x.map(ranking_level_sort), ascending=[False, False])
hotel_sorted.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
hotel_sorted
```

#### What I Got

| name | price | level | reviews |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Miniinn - Double Room with Private Bathroom | 47 | Exceptional | 1 |
| The Empire Brunei | 309 | Excellent | 1464 |
| Higher Hotel | 24 | Excellent | 865 |
| Radisson Hotel Brunei | 120 | Excellent | 1314 |
| Abdul Razak Hotel Apartment | 59 | Excellent | 129 |

#### What I Expect

| name | price | level | reviews |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Miniinn - Double Room with Private Bathroom | 47 | Exceptional | 1 |
| The Empire Brunei | 309 | Excellent | 1464 |
| Radisson Hotel Brunei | 120 | Excellent | 1314 |
| Higher Hotel | 24 | Excellent | 865 |
| Abdul Razak Hotel Apartment | 59 | Excellent | 129 |

So far, I've managed to sort by `level`, and is not followed by `reviews`. The `key` argument in `sort_values` can only take one lambda expression. I'm not sure how this can be solved, any pointers?

Comment: Very good question - code, sample data and expected ouput.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` is applied for both columns. It finds no matches for `reviews` and returns `NaN` values. So you need to replace those by the original values using `fillna`, like this:

```
hotel_sorted = hotel.sort_values(by=["level", "reviews"],  
                                 key=lambda x: x.map(ranking_level_sort).fillna(x), 
                                 ascending=False)
hotel_sorted.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print (hotel_sorted)
                                          name  price        level  reviews
0  Miniinn - Double Room with Private Bathroom     47  Exceptional        1
1                            The Empire Brunei    309    Excellent     1464
2                        Radisson Hotel Brunei    120    Excellent     1314
3                                 Higher Hotel     24    Excellent      865
4                  Abdul Razak Hotel Apartment     59    Excellent      129
```

Comment: @Michel de Ruiter - thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix to your code (makes mapping apply to 'level' series only):

```
hotel_sorted = hotel.sort_values(by=["level", "reviews"],  
       key=lambda x: x if x.name!='level' else x.map(ranking_level_sort), 
       ascending=[False, False])
```